# Build an rdb2rdf system

Tags: relational-database, sparql, rdf, etl, semantic-web

I'm building an rdb2rdf system.I'm confused what is better to materialize the output data base (convert all input relational database into triples) or to convert sparql query to sql?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking what "an rdb2rdf system" is? If you don't know what you're building, why ask us? Why are you building it?

Comment: Both ways would need to decide on the mapping between SQL tables/columns, etc. and the RDF schema. But in general, this question is too broad and opinion based, thus, bad for Stackoverflow. Can be closed.

Comment: RDF triples represent binary predicates (subject-predicate-object). However, relational databases are capable of representing n-ary predicates.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/ defined two standards:

- A Direct Mapping of Relational Data to RDF (DM)
- R2RML: RDB to RDF Mapping Language

It's a good idea to follow these standards. Both approaches you mention are viable.

- Static conversion allows you to use a standard triple store, can be faster, but introduces a lag (data is not up-to-the-second). There are a number of open source implementations you can use
- SPARQL translation is harder. It's always possible for DM, but not always for R2RML. The only implementation that comes to mind right now is Capsenta Ultrawrap (commercial)

Comment: Another "live" implementation is [Linked Data Views](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration) in [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) ([Open Source Edition](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex) only supports this feature over local SQL data, within the same Virtuoso instance; [Commercial Edition](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download) also supports Linked Data Views over remote SQL data sources). _(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces Virtuoso and employs me.)_